# Why doesn't the binary package get reinstalled by apt-get or building from source?

Tags: bash, debian, path, asterisk

I'm trying to install Asterisk on my Debian wheezy server. For this I first did the simple

```
sudo apt-get install asterisk
```

This worked flawlessly. Afterwards asterisk was running and I could enter the CLI of it using :

```
asterisk -rvvv
```

After some messing around I dumped asterisk and reinstalled again:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge asterisk
sudo apt-get install asterisk
```

This reinstalled successfully, and `sudo service asterisk status` shows `[ ok ] Asterisk PBX is running.`, but I cannot enter the CLI anymore (`asterisk -rvvv` says `-bash: asterisk: command not found`).

So I tried installing it from source using [this simple guide](http://voipfreak.net/how-to-install-asterisk-on-debian/). All steps go well, and I can get asterisk up and running again. But yet again, the CLI refuses to start with another `-bash: asterisk: command not found`).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? Or can anybody point me in the right direction? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How the shell finds your programs

When you type `foo` in the command-line of your shell, it looks `foo` up in a set of paths defined by your shell's `PATH` environment variable (which you can inspect by running `echo $PATH`).

So my guess is simpe: the asterisk package you had before reinstalling had the `asterisk` binary located in a place listed in your user's `$PATH` and the package installed afterwards had it installed elsewhere.

You can check this easily by correlating `echo $PATH` in your shell with the output of

```
$ dpkg -L asterisk | grep bin/asterisk
```

In any case, you can run your binary program by specifying its full pathname.

#### Pathname resulution caching in the shells

Another possibility, though less likely, is pathname resolution caching.  Interactive shells, `bash` included, only look up a bare program's name through the list in `$PATH` once, and then remember that full location they've found.  If you then remove the program from that location, the shell will be unable to run it anymore, even if the program's file is now accessible in some other place listed in the `$PATH`.

You can help the shell by running `hash -r` in it (please see `help hash` in your `bash` prompt).

#### Miscellanea

Note that in the general case, when you do

```
apt-get remove --purge asterisk
apt-get install asterisk
```

that is, perform a remove+install cycle, the version of a package *as known to the APT system based on the archives made available to it* is installed.  That is, if you have installed your hand-built version directly via `dpkg -i ...`, APT won't attempt to find and install this same version when you later remove and install the package with the same name.

If you want to make your hand-built `asterisk` package be available for general installation, you'd have to maintain a proper local Debian repository (`reprepro` is properly the simplest tool to use, also see `apt-ftparchive`), make it known to your local APT system and also possibly make packages from that repository preferred using [APT preferences](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).

Comment: Turns out the binary was actually in `/usr/bin` which wasn't in my PATH. Just added it in .bashrc, which solved it. Thanks for the inspiration and the extensive and exellent answer! You made my day!